# Sending file through HTTP request

Tags: javascript, node.js

I tried to receive the file and store it in the multer storage 
[Node js code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/M9jvi.png)

```
enter code here
```

app.post('/createLicence', upload.single('photo'),function(req, res ,next) {
        // any logic goes here

```
   console.log("filename" ,req.body.name)
    if (!req.file) {
        console.log("No file received");
        return res.send({
          success: false
        });

      } else {
        console.log('file received');

        var function_name = 'createLicence'
     var arguments_array =  [req.file.path,'Raghav','Mumbai','Approved']
     invoke = require('/Users/sanjeev.natarajan/fabric-samples/fabcar/invoke.js');
     invoke.invokechaincode(function_name,arguments_array)  
     return res.send({
        success: true 
      })
      }

});
```

but i am receiving no file is received[i have send the request through postman](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ngu46.png)

Comment: Please include all the relevant information (code, errors, logs) as text not as images.

Comment: i am not receiving any error but req.file is undefined

Comment: Please, add code and stack trace and configurations.

Comment: node js code is added

Comment: Please, paste your code into your question as **text**. And format it with `CTRL-k`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

-
From : https://www.npmjs.com/package/multer

In order to use the multer package, you have first to define a few parameters so that it can work on your fileDirectory.

In your server.js :

```
let multer = require('multer');

let storage = multer.diskStorage({
  destination: function(req, file, cb) {
    cb(null, '/path/to/storage/')
  },
  filename: function(req, file, callback) {
    callback(null, file.originalname + '-' + Date.now());
  }
});

let upload = multer({
  storage: storage
});
```

Now, configure your route

```
router.route('/your/payload')
  .post(authController.isAuthenticated, upload.any(), albumController.postFile)
```

Note that `upload.any()` will allow you to upload multiple different formatted files at once. Feel free to use any other kind of upload.method() depending on your needs.

From this point, `multer` already is doing its job, however you might want to keep track of the files uploaded on your server.

So, in your own module, the logic is pretty much straight forward :

(I'm assuming that you're using mongoose models since you're not giving much information, but that's not the relevant part anyway)

```
exports.postFile = async (req, res) => {
if (!req || !req.files || !req.files[0]) return res.status(400).send("Bad request.");

for (let i = 0; req.files[i]; i++) {
  await File.create({
    path: req.files[i],
    originalName: req.files[i].originalName,
    mimetype: req.files[i].mimetype,
    owner: req.user.userId
    }, (err, file) => {
    if (err) console.log("Something went wrong: " + err); else {
       // Do something with file
      }
    });
  }
  return res.status(418).send("I'm a teapot.");
}
```

This configuration and middleware use is ONLY for testing purpose, never ever let anyone upload something to your server without carefully handle that uploading process (file integrity, resource management, ...). An open uploading system can become a very wide backdoor getting straight to your server.

Hope this helps, 
regards.

Comment: this is for just uploading file and then creating the hash in ipfs. this works fine thanks a lot